# Finding Parts of String jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, keyword

## Problem

How do I find a specific set of words in a string (gval in this case) define being the specific wordset?

```
if(gval.indexOf("define") > -1){
    console.log("Yo! gval contains Define");
}
var gval = input.val().trim().toLowerCase();
```

#### Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "*find a specific set of words*"?

Comment: @DavidThomas Just to find for instance "define" in the string define chocolate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find a *"wordset"* then you will need to use an `Array` of the expected *word(s)* needed  and then, taking advantage of the [$.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) function provided by *jQuery* library, you can try the following:

---

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/t52aLmcz/

```
var text = 'this is a text that contains defined word', 
    textWords = text.split(' '), // create array of text words
    expectedWords = ['defined', 'this'], // expected words to be found
    word;

for (var i in textWords) {
    word = textWords[i];
    if($.inArray(word, expectedWords) != -1) {
        break; // if one of the expected words is found, do a break
    }
}

if (word) { // word exists
    console.log('Your text contains: ' + word);
}
```

Comment: That is great but it only finds first word in array? I don't know why.

Comment: @WitchKingofAngmar the process will stop when one of the expected words is found. However, you can remove the `break` statement and start storing them in an `array` to have the set of words that were found and then print them. Is just a matter to adjust the code as needed, I only gave you an example.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can solve your problem using .split().
Make an array wich contains every word. Loop through it to check if the word is equal to 'gval'.

**Example**

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id=gval>In this sentence is a word gval and i want to find it! maybe more then once? gval gval</h1>
    <h2 id=outcome></h2>
    <script>
        var string = document.getElementById('gval').innerHTML; //create the string you want to check.
        var stringArray = string.split(' ');// Split the string every time it sees an space ' '.
        var ammount = 0;//This wil be the ammount of 'gval' there are in the sentence.
        for(i = 0; i < stringArray.length;i++){ // Loop through the length of the array.
            if(stringArray[i] == 'gval'){ // Check if the word is the same as 'gval'.
                ammount++;//If the word is the same as 'gval' increment ammount with +1.
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('outcome').innerHTML = ammount;//set the text in the H2 with id outcome to the ammount.
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for case insensitive search than use this. you first need to set variable gval and then only you can check indexOf

```
var gval = input.val().trim().toLowerCase();
if(gval.indexOf("define") > -1){
console.log("Yo! gval contains Define");
}
```